# Java SQL statement not given an error neither a resultset

Tags: java, sql, database, resultset

I have the following SQL statement in my program:

```
"SELECT ANTAL_KALD,BESVARET_25_SEK,((BESVARET_25_SEK/nullif(ANTAL_KALD,0))*100) as answer_percent,TIDSPUNKT,QUEUE "
                +"FROM KS_DRIFT.PERO_NKM_KØ_OVERSIGT WHERE TIDSPUNKT BETWEEN '"+start.getYear()+"-"+start.getMonthOfYear()+"-"+start.getDayOfMonth()+
                "' AND '"+end.getYear()+"-"+end.getMonthOfYear()+"-"+end.getDayOfMonth()+
                "'";
```

this doesnt give me any resultset

the test `System.out.println(rs.next())` is `false`

However when i in my DB writes the following:

```
select QUEUE,
ANTAL_KALD,
BESVARET_25_SEK,
((BESVARET_25_SEK/nullif(ANTAL_KALD,0))*100) as answer_percent,
TIDSPUNKT
from KS_DRIFT.PERO_NKM_KØ_OVERSIGT Where TIDSPUNKT BETWEEN '2012-12-01' AND '2012-12-02' ORDER BY QUEUE
```

i get results.. So what is the problem? it is not giving me an error or anything

Comment: post your JDBC code, and why are you using Simple statement and making yourself prone to SQL Injection ?? use preparedstatements instead

Comment: your queries seems to be different

Comment: I would print and make sure start and end are valid dates.

Comment: Also, your queries are not the same. Take a 2nd look.

Comment: How would you make this statement as a preparedStatement?

Comment: @RohitJain no QUEUE are placed differently however this should not change the outcome and after testing it hasnt.

Comment: @MarcRasmussen take a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR Does this work with oracle databases aswell?

Comment: yeepp, it does :) check @yogendra singh's answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `start` and `end` are `java.sql.Date` objects(if not please convert), I advice you to use `PreparedStatement` with `setDate()` to set the date as below:

```
   String sql = "SELECT ANTAL_KALD,BESVARET_25_SEK, "+
               " ((BESVARET_25_SEK/nullif(ANTAL_KALD,0))*100) as answer_percent, "+
               " TIDSPUNKT,QUEUE "
               +"FROM KS_DRIFT.PERO_NKM_KØ_OVERSIGT "+
               " WHERE TIDSPUNKT BETWEEN ?  AND ?";
   PreparedStatement qStmt=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
   qStmt.setDate(1, start);
   qStmt.setDate(1, end);


   ResultSet rs = qStmt.executeQuery();
```

**EDIT**: To get `java.sql.Date` from Joda `DateTime` Object, please do the below:

```
   java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(start.toDate().getTime());
   java.sql.Date endDate   = new java.sql.Date(end.toDate().getTime());
```

Use these converted objects in the query.

Comment: start and end are Joda time can i pass those without converting?